# database is not connecting in iis

Tags: asp.net, mysql, iis

I have two database.

```
<add name="OdonovanTestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ODO-SRV004\;Initial Catalog=OdonovanTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="rackleyConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=ODO-SRV004\;Initial Catalog=rackleyTest;Integrated Security=true"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I host my asp .net application in iis. The first database is connecting which is odonovantest.

But the database rackletTest is not connecting. Both database lies in same sql server.

Can any one give me solution?

Comment: Did you spell your database name wrong (`racklet` vs `rackley`)?  There's not much to go on here.  Any error messages, or what is the exact problem?

Comment: what is not connecting? What's happening? Nothing or you have exception or error?

Comment: @Jobert Enamno when run locally using vs 2010 my application is working fine. But the problem is when i host in iis the data from odonovan test database accessing. But RackleyTest database is not accessing means any data from RackleyTest is not showing when running the program.

Answer (score 0):

you can call your connection string explicitly as code bellow:

```
string connectionString = SampleApplication.Properties.Settings.Default.rackleyConnectionString1;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    // put code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you are using Windows Authentication or Sql Server Authentication. 
In Web.config:
For Sql Server Authentication:

For Windows Authentication:

And then your have to define in codebehind also.

Comment: using  windows authentication.